# Selenium webdriver eats up all memory in loop

Tags: python, linux, selenium-webdriver, debian, phantomjs

I have problem with processes and memory usage. I created a script to parse some webpages using selenium webdriver with PhantomJS. The script works fine, but my code need some optimization.

I start script and after a moment, my memory is full because I have a lot of phantomjs processes.

**How to fix this?** my code:

server.py

```
from selenium import webdriver
import radio
import urllib2
class Server(object):
    running = False
    radio_dir = "db/radio.txt"
    def __init__(self):
        """Choose browser from selenium webdrivers"""
        self.browser2 = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.r = radio.RadioParser(self.browser2)
        self.running = True
    def loop(self):
        """main server loop"""
        while self.running:
            radio_str = self.r.parse()
            self.save(self.radio_dir, radiozet_str)
            time.sleep(30)
    def save(self, location, string):
        """Put location and string to override db files"""
        try:
            file = open(location, 'w')
            file.write(string)
        except IOError:
            print "IOError"
        finally:
            file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Server()
    s.loop()
```

and radio.py

```
class RadioParser(object):
    url = "http://www.radiourl/index.html"
    def __init__(self, browser):
        self.driver = browser
    def parse(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        song = (self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("artist").text +u" - " +
                self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("album").text)
        print song
        return str(song)
```

Comment: I guess you are the one who is too hungry with the memory. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should close your webdriver, using

```
self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Only if you create the webdriver in the loop.

Comment: Well, this is the closest solution I've reached, but I don't want to close Selenium webdriver (mine is PhantomJS) and open up again, this takes a lot of time.